# C# retrieving data from DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, dataset, readxml

I have started with a simple DataTable, in which I have written to a XML file. On the next time the program runs, I want to check to see if the XML file exits, and read it.

It appears writing the xml is fine, and I believe reading it is fine, but I cannot seem to get any of the data within the DataSet after I have read from it..

```
ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Computers\config.xml");
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Computers\config.xml"))
{
    ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Computers\config.xml");
    //comboBox.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()); doesn't work
    comboBox.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);  //this counts 3 rows
}
```

I receive this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find column 1.

here's a look at my XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
    <Table1>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Version>1.1.1.1</Version>
        <Code />
        <Location>C:\Computers\test.txt</Location>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <Name>test2</Name>
        <Version />
        <Code />
        <Location />
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <Name>test3</Name>
        <Version />
        <Code />
        <Location />
    </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

I'm just trying to get the "Name" Field from each row, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `C:\ <?xml version` correct or `<?xml version` in your XML file.

Comment: just <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

Comment: I don't get the error you get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your XML into C:\computer
And run the code

```
DataSet ds =new DataSet();

if (File.Exists(@"C:\Computers\config.xml"))
{
            ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Computers\config.xml");

            //comboBox.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()); doesn't work
            comboBox.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);  //this counts 3 rows
}
```

comboBox.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() is Tesy1
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count is 3

so, I think problem is not here.

Comment: Right, the count works fine, but if I use the commented out code I cannot seem to get the actual value "Test1" "Test2" or "Test3"

Comment: Figured it out, It was the scope of my Dataset, for whatever reason I put it at the top within my main window. Changing the scope of the object resolved my issue. Not exactly sure why it didn't like being where it was, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you write

```
ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Computers\config.xml");
```

in the first line it would write a new file and thus when you read there is no data inside it. So now you should remove the first line and then check it should be running fine

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Computers\config.xml"))
{
    ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Computers\config.xml");
    comboBox.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()); //doesn't work
    comboBox.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);  //this counts 3 rows
}
```

Comment: ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Computers\config.xml"); is only in the Window closed event, I just included that above so people knew I was writing the file the that specific path

Comment: Try to debug. Put a break point on ReadXML and when your cursor reaches there go and check the file. Does it have something to read. I am sure you will get the clue ... bcoz code is running fine.

Comment: is it possible my DataTable structure is incorrect? I posted what it looks like below

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the DataTable isn't structured correctly?

```
            public DataTable predefinedPatch = new DataTable();

            predefinedPatch.Columns.Add("Name");
            predefinedPatch.Columns.Add("Version");
            predefinedPatch.Columns.Add("Code");
            predefinedPatch.Columns.Add("Location");
            //
            predefinedPatch.Rows.Add("test1", "", "", "");
            predefinedPatch.Rows.Add("test2", "", "", "");
            predefinedPatch.Rows.Add("test3", "", "", "");
```

Comment: Since you are new to SO. You can always edit your question instead of putting it as answer.

Comment: I believe when you are writing it into XML file you can see if it is structured in the way you have shown in the question. If so than it is correct. If not let us know what is your XML looks like

Comment: Got it, thanks. It was the scope of the object, I had it as a public dataset at the top within the MainWindow, it didn't have a problem with writing the xml, but I guess it has issues reading it.